# Is this Cover Column / Uncover Column pseudocode for Dancing Links correct?

Tags: algorithm

I'm doing a project with Algorithm X (Dancing Links) and I'd like to know if the pseudocode for the column covering is correct. I've not found many pseudocodes that deal with "next Row" and "next Column" like [Knuth's paper](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/papers/dancing-color.ps.gz) explains, so I haven't really been able to compare the rest to mine. But his paper is obviously not big on implementation details so I can't fully compare to it either.

I have something wrong in my Dancing Links code when I want to return multiple solutions (3888 for a 2x2 empty board, and it crashes with bigger boards) and everything is ""correct"" from the code's point of view, so I'm thinking maybe something about the concept is wrong.

This is the pseudocode (I know it looks like a lot but that's because I split it into 4 parts to minimize mistakes and making it easier to read, it's actually really really simple):

```cpp
node::cover()
/*Does the unlinking/relinking of the Cover procedures*/
{
    if this is the only visible node in the column
        null its header's firstRow and lastRow pointers
    else
        this->previousRow sets its nextRow to this->nextRow
        this->nextRow sets its previousRow to this->previousRow
        if this is the first row of this->header
            set this->header's first row as this->nextRow
        else if this is the last row of this->header
            set this->header's last row as this->previousRow
    decrease this->header's amount of rows by 1
}

node::uncover()
/*Does the unlinking/relinking of the Uncover procedures*/
{
    if this is the only visible node in the column
        set its header's firstRow and lastRow pointers to this
    else
        this->previousRow sets its nextRow to this
        this->nextRow sets its previousRow to this
        if this->nextRow is the first row of this->header
            set this->header's first row as this
        else if this->previousRow is the last row of this->header
            set this->header's last row as this
    increase this->header's amount of rows by 1
}

node::coverRow(header H)
/*Covers the entire row.*/
{
    index = this->nextNode
    while index->header is different from H
        index->cover()
        index->nextNode
}

node::uncoverRow(header H)
/*Uncovers the entire row.*/
{
    index = this->previousNode
    while index->header is different from H
        index->uncover()
        index->previousNode
}

header::cover()
/*Covers column and calls to coverRow for each row*/
{
    Set this->previousColumn as this->nextColumn
    Set this->nextColumn as this->previousColumn
    index = this->firstRow
    if my index is not null
        while index is different from lastRow
            index->coverRow(this)
            index = next row
        lastRow->coverRow(this)
}

header::uncover()
/*Uncovers column and calls to coverRow for each row*/
{
    Set previousColumn->nextColumn as this
    Set nextColumn->previousColumn as this
    index = this->lastRow
    if my index is not null
        while index is different from firstRow
            index->uncoverRow(this)
            index = previous row
        firstRow->uncoverRow(this)
}

coverColumns(node selectedRow)
/*Gets a list of the headers (from the first node to the next node of the row) and goes through them, first to last, covering them.*/
{
    get a list of the headers that are linked to that selectedRow
    index = first node of the list
    while index != end of the list
        index->header->cover()
        index = next node of the list
}

uncoverColumns(node selectedRow)
/*Gets a list of the headers (from the first node to the next node of the row) and goes through them, last to first, covering them.*/
{
    get a list of the headers that are linked to that selectedRow
    index = last node of the list
    while index != beginning of the list
        index->header->cover()
        index = previous node of the list
}
```

The first thing you have is the selectedRow, and you have to call uncoverColumns with that as a parameter. From there I think (though, right now considering it's not working I'm not so sure) you have to get all the columns that are satisfied by that row. Once you have the three of them, you cover all their rows.

I hope the pseudocode is readable, it's the first time I've written pseudocode for someone else.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Why don't you show **real code** that we can execute ? It's extremely hard to spot a mistake in such a huge amount of peudocode without being able to execute it in a debugger. Plus there is a chance that there is a mistake in the translation pseudocode <-> real code.

Comment: @hivert Because the real code needs a huge structure to go with it and I can't post a minimal example of that, so last time I posted a question with the huge amount of code needed, I got downvoted. If you're interested in the code (although, like I said, it's hard to provide a minimal example, I'd be at it the whole day and I need to keep debugging since I need to turn this in tomorrow) you can find it here [link](https://github.com/Pawbla/futoshiki). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the operations in `uncover` in the opposite order than in `cover`. Currently you do them in the same order.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by the opposite order? I thought I was doing it in the opposite order. Besides changing the header::uncover so the while is "over" the column reconnection, I'm not sure how I'd do that.

Comment: I remember I had that problem when I implemented the dancing links algorithm a few years ago myself. Some changes were not correctly undone because of a wrong order of statements. I don't see the exact spot in your pseudo code now.

Comment: Well, I changed that part I said, it was still not working, and then I changed a thing about my algorithm as well, and it works. Dunno if it made a big difference, but I'll mark your answer as correct anyways! Thanks so much!